# Android - Swiping without Tabs

Tags: android, swipe

**NoteActivity Code:**

```
public class NoteActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener 
{
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
        private ActionBar actionBar;
        // Tab titles
        private String[] tabs = {"Note", "Note Info"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**TabsPageAdapter.Java**

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) 
        {
        case 0:
            return new NoteFragment();
        case 1:

            return new NoteInfoFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 2;
    }
}
```

So basically, I used an example of Tabs View and got the Tabs working and it looks like this: [image]

What would I have to do to make it just swipeable without the Tabs showing. An example is like Snapchat. It definitely uses the Swipe view control but the tabs are hidden. Can someone please show me how to get this done?

Comment: Use only the ViewPager and remove the tabs.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me how its done? I would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You already have the code for it above, you just need to remove the parts that add tabs to the actionbar, as well as parts that synchronize the selected tab with the current page.

Comment: I'll make changes and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Karakuri! Did exactly what you told me and got it to work :) Add the answer And I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a ViewPager in your code, all you have to do is remove the code that creates the ActionBar tabs (under the comment `// Adding tabs`), as well as the code that synchronizes the tab selection with the current page (start with the `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and the `ActionBar.TabListener` callbacks and see if anything breaks).